# The menubar component of the primeVue doesn’t highlight the active/focus item properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

We are developing an electron-based app with the front end written mainly in Vue.js and primeVue. I am a beginner and facing difficulty with the menubar component from primeVue. The first menubar item is always taken as the active one. This means that the first item is always highlighted, no matter of which item I clicked on. In devTools, I have noticed that every time I click on any item, the class p-focus appears at the first menubar item. Does anyone know where the problem could be or how to deactivate this p-focus class? Thanks a lot for any hints.

The code below:

```
<template>
    <Menubar :model="items" class="mymenu">
        <template #end>
            <Button icon="pi pi-user" class="mr-2" />
            <Button @click="$router.go(-1)" label="Back" />
        </template>
    </Menubar>
</template>


<script>
import Menubar from 'primevue/menubar';
import Button from "primevue/button";

export default {
    name:"Menu",
    components: {
        Menubar,
        Button
},
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {label:'Item 1',to:"/operators"},
                {label:'Item 2',to:"/sites"},
                {label:'Item 3',to:"/ropes"}

            ]
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Attached, two screen-shots:

- [the menubar when I clicked on the last item and the first one is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK28d.png)
- [the p-focus class in the source code from devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7CCz.png)

First, I have tried to define the pseudoclass, like p-menuitem:focus or p-menutitem:active, to style the background color. That did not work for me. Then, I went step back to style the existing components by defining my class for the menu. (following the [instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZV1w65VONg)). But this did not work for me neither. Even if I increased the specificity by using !important value.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
::v-deep(.mymenu){
        .p-menuitem{
            background-color: aqua !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.p-menuitem {
    &.p-focus {
        > .p-menuitem-content {
            background-color: aqua !important;
        }
    }
}
```